# Performance concerns from creating a "GIF" by rapidly switching out SVG elements in the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering if I should be concerned about performance / any memory issues if I'm creating GIF-like effects by rapidly cycling between multiple SVG elements?

For the sake of resolution and to [maintain accurate transparency](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15549/how-can-i-remove-the-white-pixels-around-the-edges-when-exporting-a-transparent) I'm not using actual GIFs for this effect. Basically in React, I have an array of SVGs created like

```
const svg1 = () => { return <svg>...</svg> };
const svg2 = () => { return <svg>...</svg> };
...etc.
```

And to make the animation, I cycle through them, rendering only one at a given time.

I'm wondering if it's better to have all SVG elements already in the DOM and just modifying the opacity of each? And also for future reference, how I can benchmark this performance myself?

Comment: I'm not sure about which is the best case, but you can benchmark performance using the developer tools in a browser. There are tabs for `Performance` and `Memory`. Starting a capture will allow you to see the operations responsible during the peak usage. [Here's](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance) an example doc for Chrome dev tools

Answer (score 2):

I encourage you to check this example of animating svgs using 'react-move' (animation library) and useTick (react hook) https://dev.to/tornord/how-to-create-animated-svg-using-react-296l. There is a useTick hook available in react functional components. You can use it to imitate a GIF like effect. Please check out this example with useTick https://reactpixi.org/hooks#usetick

As it comes to performance: I think it is better to loop through array of SVGs, because if you use opacity, then it means you will have to preload all SVGs at rendering the page. If you have plethora of those SVG elements that would be resource consuming on a client side when the page loads.

Comment: Thanks for the resource, however it seems like these examples animate a pre-existing SVG component. What I'm trying to do is kind of like a "cartoon" where each frame is a different SVG and I want to flash between each one. So I'll keep your second point in mind and try the array of SVGs